# Object array not being updated in memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, handle

I have an employees array,

```
[
    {
      "employeeNum": 1,
      "firstName": "Foster",
      "lastName": "Thorburn",
      "email": "fthorburn0@myCompany.com",
      "SSN": "935-74-9919",
      "addressStreet": "8 Arapahoe Park",
      "addresCity": "New York",
      "addressState": "NY",
      "addressPostal": "20719",
      "maritalStatus": "single",
      "isManager": true,
      "employeeManagerNum": null,
      "status": "Full Time",
      "department": 2,
      "hireDate": "4/30/2014"
    },
    {
      "employeeNum": 2,
      "firstName": "Emmy",
      "lastName": "Trehearne",
      "email": "etrehearne1@myCompany.com",
      "SSN": "906-43-6273",
      "addressStreet": "66965 Shelley Circle",
      "addresCity": "New York",
      "addressState": "NY",
      "addressPostal": "33605",
      "maritalStatus": "single",
      "isManager": true,
      "employeeManagerNum": null,
      "status": "Full Time",
      "department": 2,
      "hireDate": "6/25/2016"
    },
      etc
 ]
```

And a route in my `server.js` file,

```
app.post("/employee/update", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    data.updateEmployee(req.body).then((data) => {
        res.redirect("/employees");   
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("An error was encountered: " + err);
    })
});
```

And `updateEmployee()` is defined as,

```
module.exports.updateEmployee = function(employeeData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let flag = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i].employeeNum == employeeData.employeeNum) {
                employees[i] = employeeData;
                employees[i].employeeNum = i + 1;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(flag) {
            console.log("NO DATA FOUND");
            reject("No data found");
        } else {
            resolve();
        }
    });
}
```

The `console.log(req.body);` line executes properly in my `app.post` route. Is it something to do with `employeeNum`? I've tried doing something like this,

```
        for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i].employeeNum == employeeData.employeeNum) {
                employees[i] = employeeData;
                employees[i].employeeNum = i + 1;
                flag = true;
                console.log(employees[i] + "\nDKJSFSFS");
            }
        }
```

But the `console.log(...)` in the loop doesn't even print..
Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see, in the code you've published, where the `employee` array is populated. You are passing a `employeeData` argument to `updateEmployee` (albeit as a string rather than an array). Look in your console for errors.

Comment: Why are you doing this async?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

In my form for updating an employee, the `employeeNum` isnt an accessible value; it functions as an index. So therefore, I would not be able to compare

`(employees[i].employeeNum == employeeData.employeeNum)`

I fixed it by comparing the SSN value.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        if (employees[i].SSN == employeeData.SSN) {
            employees[i] = employeeData;
            employees[i].employeeNum = i + 1;
            flag = true;
        }
    }
```